# Making the displayquote environment display references in footnotes

Tags: footnotes, quoting, csquotes

I am trying to get the `displayquote` environment of the `csquotes` package to put the references to the cited works in a footnote. I am trying the following setup

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{displayquote}[{\cite[235]{Testreference}}]   
Some really smart quote.
\end{displayquote}
\end{document}
```

I want the `displayquote` environment to display the reference as a footnote at the bottom of the page with the footnotemark displayed at the end of the quotation after the punctuation mark `.`, but it seems that it doesn't work when I "naively" try and put the `\cite` command as `\footcite`, as it puts the footnotemark in parentheses in a seperate line just after the quoted text.

Comment: Try putting \renewcommand{\mkcitation}[1]{\footnote{#1}} in the preamble.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, this does produce the footnote-style citation that I want, but the footnotemark is still "hanging" so to speak all by itself on a seperate line just after the quoted material, which is not what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to define a new environment that sets up a footnote-style citation rather than use the traditional `displayquote` environment. Below I defined `footcitedquote` which does that:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\newenvironment{footcitedquote}[1][]
  {% \begin{footcitedquote}[.]
   \let\mkcitation\footnote% Citations will be footnotes
   \def\optarg{#1}% Capture optional argument
   % Set up start of displayquote environment
   \edef\envstart{\noexpand\begin{displayquote}\if$\optarg$\else[\noexpand\optarg]\fi}%
   \envstart}
  {\end{displayquote}}% \end{footcitedquote}
\begin{document}

\begin{displayquote}[{\cite[235]{Testreference}}]
Some really smart quote.
\end{displayquote}

\begin{footcitedquote}[{\cite[235]{Testreference}}]
Some really smart quote.
\end{footcitedquote}

\begin{footcitedquote}
Some really smart quote.
\end{footcitedquote}

\end{document}
```

The change to `\mkcitation` (`\let`ting it to `\footnote`) is localized to the environment.

Comment: Thank, you this worked out really nice!

Is it possible to use this new environment in conjunction with a truncation of the line-spacing, since that would be really neat for longer quotations so they don't fill up as much space?

Comment: @Bartuc: You can change the font or other formatting as you wish, perhaps by setting a quotation `style`.